# Problems with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand the concept of pointers. So I wrote a code (from a book I have) but It doesn't complile. Can't understand what is wrong, again I wrote exactly how it is in the book, and I checked if there are some mistakes, but I can't find any...

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var = 1;
int *ptr;
 
int main(void)
{
    ptr = &var;   
     
    printf("Var = %d", var);
    printf("Var = %d", *ptr);
    
    printf("The adress of the variable = %d", &var);
    printf("The adress = %d", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I got:

```
ø.c:13:47: error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has
type 'int *' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("The adress of the variable = %d", &var);
                                         ~~   ^~~~ ø.c:14:31: error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'
[-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("The adress = %d", ptr);
                         ~~   ^~~
```

Comment: `%d` is for integer values, and you are trynig to print a pointer value (i.e. an address).

Answer (score 3):

Use "%p" for pointer (not "%d").

Comment: You might add that the pointer value must be cast to `(void*)`

Comment: I don't think the cast is really required here.
Because, I think that the function `printf` is just interpreting the arguments as specified.
(So I'm surprised that the compiler does such a kind check.)

Is this my thinking wrong for C specification?

Comment: `printf` expects to get a `void*`. Due to missing parameter list, the compiler cannot do automatic conversion. You must do it explicitely.

Comment: Thanks.
Now, I understand the problem is as "when void* and other pointer types (such as int*) do not become the same bit pattern, ...".

Answer (score -1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int var = 1;
     int *ptr;
     ptr = &var;   
 
     printf("Var = %d", var);
     printf("Var = %d", *ptr);

     printf("The adress of the variable = %p", &var);
     printf("The adress = %p", ptr);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are considered poor answers. Also in an answer code should be properly indented,